# Integer program in which at least one of three inequalities holds

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Formulate the following Integer Program considering alternative constraints

\begin{align}\max \qquad &2x-79y\\[0.2cm]\text{ subject to}\qquad& 0\le x\le 20 \, \text{ and }\, 0\le y\le 30\end{align}

and at least one of the following inequalities holds:
\begin{align}-2x+3y&\ge 0\\[0.2cm]5x-4y&\ge0\\[0.2cm]7x+8y&\le40\end{align}

Comment: You mean $y$ instead of $x_2$ and $x$ instead of $x_1$ in the constraints?

Comment: Thanks @JimmyR. Any help with the Formulation of this problem?

Comment: You can write the first as $y\ge \frac23x$ and the second $y\le \frac54x$. Now take a point $(x,y)$ that satisfies $y<\frac23x$ (that is a point that fails the first). Then, since $x\ge0$, necessarily $y<\frac23x\le \frac54x$ and therefore it satisfies the second. Hence, either the first or the second (or both) are always satisfied and you are done. What do you think?

Comment: @JimmyR. Yeah makes sense, but I'm getting confused about what that means, does that mean that the only relevant criteria are the singular x and y ones at the top? (As in one would just write the IP using a sum that satisfied the top 2 criteria and not the bottom 3)

Comment: It means, that you can drop these criteria as at least one is always satisfied. They actually give no restriction at all. If you need that all three of them are satisfied then this is different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jimmy says, it is a pretty badly designed example, as the intersection of the complement of the constraints is empty so some constraint will always hold.

However, I think the problem designer (your teacher?) wants you to create a big-M model. To ensure N of the constraints $f_i(x)\leq 0$ to hold, you can write it as $f_i(x)\leq M(1-\delta_i)$ where $\delta_i$ is binary, and then introduce a suitable constraint on $\delta$, and select a suitable constant $M$ to make the model valid (details left to the student)

Comment: Struggling to see how to solve this using the big-M constraint but thanks and i kind of see where you're coming from!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

My final answer to this question when given it was:

max $2x_1-79x_2$
subject to
$0\le x_1\le 20, 0\le x_2 \le 30$
$2x_1-3x_2\le M_1 (1-y_1)$
$4x_2-5x_1\le M_2(1-y_2)$
$7x_1+8x_2-40\le M_3 (1-y_3)$
$\sum^3_{j=1}y_j\ge1$
$y_j\in \{0,1\}$ for $j=1,2,3$

Choose $M_j$ so ignored constraints will not be binding.
These values are
$M_1\ge40$
$M_2\ge120$
$M_3\ge340$